# Is Comparator a class or interface, and, if latter, how come it can be instantiated?

Tags: java, instantiation, comparator

I've been trying to wrap my head around comparing objects in Java and, consequently, the `Comparable` and `Comparator` entities. I've been reading Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, third edition.

Page 70:

> In Java 8, the `Comparator` interface was outfitted with a set of comparator
>   construction methods, which enable fluent construction of comparators.In Java 8, the Comparator interface was outfitted with a set of comparator
>   construction methods, which enable fluent construction of comparators.

Page 71:

> The `Comparator` class has a full complement of construction methods.

So, which is it?

I looked up in java specs, which state that `Comparator` is indeed an interface, which I'm assuming is the correct answer to my question. So is this just a mistake in the book?

Bloch goes on to say:

> The static method, named `comparing`, has two overloadings. One takes a key
>   extractor and uses the keys’ natural order. The second takes both a key extractor and a comparator to be used on the extracted keys. There are three overloadings of the instance method, which is named `thenComparing`.

If `Comparator` is an interface, how come it can have instance methods? I always thought that interfaces are non-instantiable. Or am I reading it completely wrong?

Comment: It just struck me: is it an instance of a class that implements the `Comparator` interface that's meant in the book?

Comment: Interfaces can't be directly instantiated, but they can be implemented by classes. An instance of a class that implements the interface is an instance of the interface.

Comment: With Java 8, interfaces can have static methods. They can also have concrete instance methods, but not instance fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is, as you say, an interface. The API doc is canonical in this respect, as it's generated from the code itself.
2. Thus referring to it as a class is a minor slip of the tongue.
3. Since Java 8 though, [interfaces can have non-abstract instance methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), and that's what's going on with [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-). (Note the `default` keyword.)